# How to test react form onSubmit with formik and react testing library?

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I'm learning how to test react form and I don't understand why my test does not success ?

```js
    Expected: {"email": "john.dee@someemail.com", "firstName": "John", "lastName": "Dee", "password": "password"}

    Number of calls: 0
```

my form is simple:

```js
const SignUpForm = () => {
  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: initialValues,
    validationSchema: schema,
    onSubmit: submitForm,
  });

  return (
    <form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
      <label htmlFor="firstName">First Name</label>
      < input ..>
      <label htmlFor="lastName">Last Name</label>
      < input ..>
      <label htmlFor="password">password</label>
      < input ..>
      <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
      < input ..>
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default SignUpForm;
```

and the test:

```js
test("rendering and submitting a basic Formik form", async () => {
  const handleSubmit = jest.fn();
  render(<SignUpForm onSubmit={handleSubmit} />);

  userEvent.type(screen.getByLabelText(/First Name/i), "John");
  userEvent.type(screen.getByLabelText(/Last Name/i), "Dee");
  userEvent.type(screen.getByLabelText(/Email/i), "john.dee@someemail.com");
  userEvent.type(screen.getByLabelText(/password/i), "password");

  userEvent.click(screen.getByRole("button", { name: /Submit/i }));

  await waitFor(() =>
    expect(handleSubmit).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
      email: "john.dee@someemail.com",
      firstName: "John",
      lastName: "Dee",
      password: "password",
    })
  );
});
```

I did export "initialValues", "schema" and "onsubmit" in others files, and when I do test myself all seems to be working properly.

In the console, when the test is done I can see my form with all values filled like:

```js
 <input id="email" name="email" type="email" value="john.dee@someemail.com" />
```

update: here is a link with all relevant code: https://pastebin.com/CbpFFzf4

Comment: Are you using the prop "onSubmit" properly in the SignUpForm component? It seems that you are assigning a function called "submitForm" to the Formik config.

Comment: Yes I do. And this function is in its own file and I use it like this: 
const submitForm = (values) => {
  alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
};
export default submitForm;

I did try to replace "handleSubmit" in the test file by "submitform" but still not working

Comment: It looks like your `SignUpForm` doesn't have an `onSubmit` prop. Could you show us where your `submitForm` comes from?

Comment: is from ./submitForm.js

const submitForm = (values) => {
  console.log(values);
};
export default submitForm;

Answer (score 0):

Your `SignUpForm` doesn't have an onSubmit prop.

If your `onSubmit` comes from another file, you should mock the function in that module.

`import * as HelperFunctions from './submitForm.js'`

At the start of your test, you can spy on that function.

`jest.spyOn(HelperFunctions, 'onSubmit')`

then you can test if it is being called like so.

```
expect(HelperFunctions.onSubmit).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
      email: "john.dee@someemail.com",
      firstName: "John",
      lastName: "Dee",
      password: "password",
    })
```

make sure the functions are exported.

Comment: thanks but unfortunately its not working: Cannot spyOn on a primitive value; undefined given

Comment: From your comments above with the file contents, you should add an `export` in front `export const submitForm = (values) => { console.log(values); };` give that a go and let me know :)

Comment: Yes I had a export under the function "export default as submitForm". I did try export const submitForm but still not working... I don't get what's going on

By changing ```"import onSubmit from "./formik.submit"``` with ```import  {onSubmit} from "./formik.submit" ```
I get this error:
   ``` received: {"resetForm": [Function anonymous], "setErrors": [Function anonymous], "setFieldError": [Function anonymous], "setFieldTouched": [Function anonymous], "setFieldValue": [Function anonymous], "setFormikState": [Function anonymous] ```

Comment: I'm confused about where you are trying to import `import  {onSubmit} from "./formik.submit" `? Could you update your question to contain all the relevant code? including `submitForm.js `

Comment: No problem. I've done it

Comment: @jeyremd how you solved the problem, I got the same issue as yours. Can you post your answer here, it will be beneficial. Thank you